# Is there an equivalent of the Sum of Divisors function for addition (Sum of m-tuples of Addends)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I play [KenKen](http://www.kenkenpuzzle.com/) casually and get annoyed by addition cages that require 3 addends. I first came up with a formula for finding the number of ways to sum to a number with 2 addends, which was pretty easy. The number of ways to sum to $n$ with 2 addends, with positive integers only, and with no repeat addends is:

[image]

The number of ways to sum to $n$ with 3 addends, with positive integers only, and with no repeat addends is:
[image]

I spent a few hours coming up with that second formula for 3 addends. I don't have proofs for either of these formulas.

Does anyone know if something like this already exists? Can anyone help me with a proof or help me come up with a more generalized formula for $m$ addends?

Comment: You seem to regard $1+2$ as the same as $2+1$.  What you are looking for is the number of partitions of $n$ into three distinct positive parts.

Comment: Oh yeah, I do. I should've clarified that bit, no repeat sums, no repeat addends.

Comment: What you are looking for is the number of partitions of $n$ into three distinct positive parts, the same as the number of partitions of $n-3$ into three positive parts, or the number of partitions of $n-6$ into up to three parts, or the number of partitions of $n-6$ into parts no greater than $3$.  See [OEIS A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399) - plenty of formulae if you remember the adjustment by $6$